# What is the interval of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(n))(x)^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

What is the interval of convergence of the power series  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(n))(x)^{n}$

= $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathrm{arccot}(n)(x)^{n}$

Radius of convergence = $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\biggl|\frac{a_{k}}{a_k+1}\biggr|$ = $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\biggl|\frac{\mathrm{arccot}(k)}{\mathrm{arccot}(k+1)}\biggr|$ = ?

I'm stuck here. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Hint: For all $n\geq 1$ we have $$\arctan(n)+\arctan(1/n)=\pi/2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ f $ defined at $ (0,+\infty) $, by

$$\forall x>0 \; f(x)=\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac 1x)$$

It is easy to check that

$$\forall x>0 \; \;\;f'(x)=0$$
thus $ f $ is constant at $ (0,+\infty)$
and
$$\forall x>0\;\; f(x)=f(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

So, $ \forall n\ge 1$,

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(n)=\arctan(\frac 1n)$$
$$\sim \frac 1n \;\;(n\to+\infty)$$

Your series has the same radius of convergence than
$$\sum \frac{x^n}{n} \;which\; is\; R=1$$